# SuiteCRM Integration With Graphql

Tags: graphql, suitecrm

I have integrate SuiteCrm with node JS using REST API but there is so many performance relates issue and for customisation need to add more custom endpoints so I have decided to integrate SuiteCRM with Graphql I have spent more times but still not getting proper documentation to integrate with Graphql.

Anyone please suggest helper library to integrate Graphql with Suitecrm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issues with the REST endpoint and we heavily rely (and like) graphql so we decided to create a helper library.

https://github.com/lionixevolve/GraphQLSuiteCRM

So far we have been using this in 5 not-so-small projects (5M record tables with 100s of users).

There are almost no custom queries everything works using SuiteCRM beans which respects logic-hooks and workflows and speed is similar to native SuiteCRM nevertheless, custom resolve methods can be created for specific scenarios (like reports or adding a large set of contacts to a target list)

Currently, its using the slim framework which allows you to write your own custom functions.

I am active on the github repo, open an issue if you have any trouble.

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your quick replay and help. Yesterday i was install your library but i didnt found good documentation how too uses your library and check queries and mutation using graphql tools.

I had just put your library in vendor folder. Would you please let me know steps how to test queries and mutation.

Thanks

Comment: I will answer your questions on github! thanks @rigal

Comment: Thanks I have check it. but getting errors i have posted errors on github.